# XML Font in STS 3.1.0

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have recently installed Spring Tool Suite 3.1.0 version for Java development. The Editor for Java code is fine. But I am not very comfortable with the font size in XML editor. I think its smaller than usual or what. I am not able to find option to change font which will effect only XML's. Or if someone can tell be settings which will be fine for both Java and XML editors.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the font to Courier New 10. Its working for both java and XML editor.